# How to avoid « Chrome OS is missing » when using Linux on Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

I wonder if it is possible to boot my chromebook from hard drive right after turning it on, without having to do Control + L on the « Chrome OS is missing » screen ?

Answer (score 0):

For most Chromebooks if you want to run Linux using Crouton you can't skip that screen.  It's there because Crouton requires disabling boot security which is what triggers the message.  Models from the last year or so have native Linux support called Crostini.  Crostini does not require disabling boot security so booting runs normally and without interruption.